# Jingle CLI client / Jitsi replacement / VOIP

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, voip

I am looking for a Jingle client for the command line.

Currently, I use Jitsi, but my dreams of not needing the GUI for more than just web-browsing are not realized due to my reliance on this program.

Does anybody know of a CLI client that supports:

- VoIP
- Communication with people on XMPP accounts
- Text chat not necessary, I have IRC for that.

And if you want to make my week:

- Full audio controls (Jack, or input/output device selection).

The system is Ubuntu 11.04 Server.

Comment: [Yate](http://yate.null.ro/pmwiki/) comes to mind.  Never got it really working, though.

Comment: Yate appears to require a client unless you want to run it as a Jabber Server. And it uses a GUI for the client (that I see).

Answer (score 0):

look on the jingle documentation http://xmpp.org/about-xmpp/technology-overview/jingle/ there aren't a client with CLI only for jingle..

Answer (score 0):

I am not at all sure about VoIP support (do you need proper SIP support, or simply computer-to-computer voice messaging?), but Pidgin comes with a command-line version called *Finch* which supports XMPP out of the box and might be a partial solution. It should also use the same buddy list, logs, settings etc. as the GUI version, so you can choose to use either depending on your needs at the moment.

Documentation: [Using Finch](https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Finch#UsingFinch).